# Prevent an elastic beanstalk app being downloaded using the AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Short background, we're a small business but our clients are much larger businesses. We have some software they subscribe to which is deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk.  Clients have their own devops teams, unlike us, and will need to manage some of the technical support. They will need access to the AWS account running the software, so they can do things like reboot the server, clear the database if they screw it up, change the EC2 instance type etc. This is OK but we want to prevent the software being downloaded outside of the AWS account.

The software is a java WAR running on Tomcat, on a single elastic beanstalk instance. We only care about limiting access to the WAR file (not the database for example).

The beanstalk application versions page appears to have no way to download the WAR file - which is good. They could SSH into the underlying EC2 instance though so presumably they could just copy the WAR out of the tomcat directory. Given the complexity of AWS there's probably other ways they could get access the WAR file too (e.g. clone the EBS volume and attach to another EC2 instance).

I assume that the machine instances available for purchase via AWS marketplace must have some form of copy protection but I've not been able to find any details on this. Also it looks like AWS only accepts marketplace vendors who are much larger than us, so marketplace option may not be open to us.

Any idea how I could prevent access to the WAR file running on elastic beanstalk while still allowing the client access to the AWS account? (Or at least make access hard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that comes to mind for this would be, **removing any EC2 SSH Key Pairs from the account**, and specifically **denying** them access to `ec2:CreateKeyPair`. Really, what you need to be doing is granting them least privilege access to the account, that is, specifically granting them access only to those actions they absolutely need.

This will go a long way, but with sufficient knowledge of AWS, it's going to be an uphill battle trying to ensure that you give them enough access to do what they need, while not giving them more than you want. I'd question if a legal option (like contracts, licenses, etc) would be a better protection for this.

Comment: Also deny access to Run Commands, which can be used to execute arbitrary scripts.